# Flutter and Dart - Widget parameter null after been assigned

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have a widget in which I am passing a JSON object on my page.dart

Inside the page.dart I am (In Order) :

- Defining the variable
- Calling the API service
- Setting the state of **API response** to **incentivesOem**

After that, I am rendering the rest of the page body and calling my widget then passing the above variables to that widget. But the service response is not captured when it returns to page.dart and **incentivesOem** is equal to null

**First - assign variables** (✅)

```
List<IncentiveOem> incentivesOem;

IncentiveServiceOem incentiveServiceOem = new IncentiveServiceOem();
```

**Second - call service** (Here in the service the api returns a JSON body ✅)

```
incentiveServiceOem.getIncentivesOem(userRequestModel).then((incentives) {
  setState(() {
    incentivesOem = incentives;
    isLoaded = true;
  });
});
```

**Third - Use the incentivesOem variable in the list**

I call the Widget `IncentivesListOem(**incentivesOem**);`
But when the page loads my `**incentivesOem** = **null**`

```
IncentivesListOem(incentivesOem: incentivesOem)
```

---

**The problem was in the end** how I was accessing the data through the widget.

```
class IncentivesListOem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<IncentivesListOem> createState() => _IncentivesListOemState();

  // Over here I needed to add "this.incentivesOem"
  IncentivesListOem({Key key, @required this.incentivesOem}) : super(key: key);

  final IncentiveOem incentivesOem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in my widget.

```
class IncentivesListOem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<IncentivesListOem> createState() => _IncentivesListOemState();

  // Over here I needed to add "this.incentivesOem"
  IncentivesListOem({Key key, @required this.incentivesOem}) : super(key: key);

  final IncentiveOem incentivesOem;
}
```

Then I was able to access the variable using widget before my variable,

```
widget.incentivesOem
```

Then I was able to output the variable like so :

```
title: Text(
  "${incentivesOem.name}",
),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've defined the variable `incentivesOem` but not initialized, initialize the variable as below,

```
List<IncentiveOem> incentivesOem = [];
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but it made no difference to the response

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet to look into it?

Comment: With null safety, the meta annotation `@required` replaced by `required` keyword, please don't use `@required`